# Unwanted white space in references

Tags: bibtex

I am getting unwanted whitespace in references.

[image: unwanted out put]

I am using these packages for my bibliography

```
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
```

These are my lines to create the bibliography

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
```

And my .bib entries are as follows

```
@booklet{NaveDP,
author = {Nave},
title = {Law of Dulong and Petit},
year = {2014},
howpublished = {url},
}

@booklet{NaveDB,
author = {Nave},
title = {Debye's Contribution to Specific Heat Theory},
year = {2014},
howpublished = {url},
}

@booklet{Brown,
author = {Robert G. Brown},
title = {First Law of Thermodynamics Summary},
year = {2004},
howpublished = {url},
}
```

Comment: It can't break the URLs correctly, try adding the package `url`?

Comment: @bombcar The url entries in the .bib file are actual urls, I couldn't post links though. But what you are saying is just add \usepackage{url} to the preamble?

Answer (score 7):

You need little help from the package `url` as mentioned by bombcar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
  @booklet{NaveDP,
author = {Nave},
title = {{Law of Dulong and Petit}},        %% note extra pair of braces
year = {2014},
howpublished = {\url{http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/dulong.html}},
}

@booklet{NaveDB,
author = {Nave},
title = {Debye's Contribution to Specific Heat Theory},
year = {2014},
howpublished = {\url{http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/debye.html}},
}

@booklet{Brown,
author = {Robert G. Brown},
title = {First Law of Thermodynamics Summary},
year = {2004},
howpublished = {\url{http://phy.duke.edu/rgb/Class/phy51/phy51/node59.html}},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[round, sort, numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
  \bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I did:

I wrote the `howpublished` data field as

```
howpublished = {\url{http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/dulong.html}},
```

using `\url` command after loading `url` package. This should be done for all urls.

To prevent bibtex from converting `Dulong and Petit` in to lower case, an extra pair of braces is used (thanks to Mico for picking it up).

```
{{Law of Dulong and Petit}}
```